# Why would this MySQL query using rand() return no results about a third of the time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of **itemproperties** that I want to grab a random **itemproperty** from, however I want the random-ness of it to lean more towards some **itemproperties** than others.

To accomplish this I've setup a column called **rarity** that stores how often that item should show up (higher = more often), and one called **rarity_position**, which is configured using this query:

```
SET @i:=0;UPDATE itemproperty SET rarity_position = @i:=@i+rarity;
```

This provides the following results:

[image: rarity results]

Then to grab a random value, I thought I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM itemproperty 
WHERE id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM itemproperty 
        WHERE rarity_position >= FLOOR
                (
                    RAND()*
                    (
                        SELECT MAX(rarity_position) FROM itemproperty
                    )
                )
        ORDER BY rarity_position 
        ASC LIMIT 1
) LIMIT 1
```

In order to select a random number with a maximum of the highest rarity_position, then grab the itemproperty with a rarity_position that is just above that.

Most of the time this works as expected, however about a third of the time no results come back.

Possibly relevant server info:

```
Software: MySQL
Software version: 5.0.95-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

You can reproduce the behaviour with this model :

```
create table itemproperty (
  id int, rarity int, rarity_position int
);
insert into itemproperty
values
  ( 1, 50, 50 ),
  ( 2, 50, 100 ),
  ( 3, 50, 150 ),
  ( 4, 50, 200 ),
  ( 5, 50, 250 ),
  ( 6, 50, 270 ),
  ( 7, 50, 320 ),
  ( 8, 50, 370 ),
  ( 9, 50, 420 ),
  ( 10, 50, 470 ),
  ( 11, 50, 520 )
;
```

If you try to do the subquery only, it works every time :

```
    SELECT id 
    FROM itemproperty 
    WHERE rarity_position >= FLOOR
            (
                RAND()*
                (
                    SELECT MAX(rarity_position) FROM itemproperty
                )
            )
    ORDER BY rarity_position 
    ASC LIMIT 1
```

But if you encapsulate it in :

```
SELECT * FROM itemproperty
WHERE id = (
 // here the above request
) LIMIT 1;
```

It will not work as expected.

What is causing it to return no results every time?

Comment: Select the result of your function to see what the calculation's result is. It'll probably reveal the problem.

Comment: +1, I can reproduce your problem and your subquery is working very well. Very interesting behaviour :-)

Comment: I've been trying to break it down for a few hours without much luck, the random values seem within the MAX value, and the IDs return valid. Another odd thing is occasionally I see two results. That could be a phpmyadmin bug though, and so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workable solution similar to zerkms method:

```
ORDER BY -LOG(1.0 – RAND()) / rarity
```

[Source](http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/10/13/selecting-random-weighted-records-from-mysql/#comment-42836)

Notably, the missing pieces seem like they might be related to this question:
[MySQL query with RAND() subquery condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363468/mysql-query-with-rand-subquery-condition)

I guess having RAND() in WHERE causes some weirdness.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM itemproperty 
ORDER BY RAND() * rarity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That's clever, and if I understand it the query incorporates the weight of each itemproperty when it sorts them?

Comment: Actually I tried using this method and it seems to completely ignore lower rarities

Comment: @Bob: for how low? For the table from example it will appear ~3.8% times

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting how the rarities work in that query; I tried inserting 723 rows and these were the results: http://imgur.com/pNLkV The only one that was under 50 in the test that appeared was 4, and even that one was only 10 down from 50.

Comment: Interestingly this seems to work: "ORDER BY -LOG(1.0 – RAND()) / rarity", from: http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/10/13/selecting-random-weighted-records-from-mysql/#comment-42836